# Extracting contiguous data from a list

Tags: python, list, output

I have a list:

```
l = [1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0]
```

I want to store each block of contiguous runs, such that:

```
Begin End Value
0     3   1
4     8   0
```

etc..

What is the best way to store this data and be able to output it in a table-like view as above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can break this up a little bit, but this does runs and lengths:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

data = [1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0]
blocks = [map(itemgetter(0), itemgetter(0, -1)(list(g))) + [k] for k, g in groupby(enumerate(data), itemgetter(1))]
# [[0, 3, 1], [4, 8, 0], [9, 11, 1], [12, 13, 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you're talking about is basically [Run Length Encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding)

I'd probably use, at least as an intermediate representation, a list of two-tuples of value and count.

I'd show an implementation of that, but karthikr's answer using itertools.groupby is better than what I was going to write.

From that data, you can determine the begin and end positions for the table you describe:

```
begin = 0
for value, length in rle_tuples:
    print begin, begin+length-1, value
    begin += length
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> L = [1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0]
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> for key,it in groupby(enumerate(L), key=itemgetter(1)):
    first_index = next(it)[0]  # at least one value will always exist
    end_index = first_index + sum(1 for _ in it)
    print('{:3}{:3}{:3}'.format(first_index, end_index, key))


  0  3  1
  4  8  0
  9 11  1
 12 13  0
```

Comment: Why do you use enumerate and itemgetter here?

Comment: @SpoonMeiser I use enumerate to delegate it index calculation. This index is extracted to first _index. Itemgetter just let me group enumerated tuples only by value without index.

Comment: @SpoonMeiser Another solutions generate temporary / lists into memory for the whole run. My solution doesn't do that, but has a bit more complicated code.